# Can we hear on Mercury, since the atmosphere is so thin?

Tags: acoustics

Since the atmosphere of Mercury is very thin, and only contains negligible amount of Oxygen, Hydrogen, and Helium, can we hear the sound over there? can the sound be transmitted by some mean?

Comment: This isn't quite a duplicate, since this takes applying the ideas from the previous question (though the two are obviously related)